# Parse retrieved image in a ListView Android

Tags: java, android, image, listview, parse-platform

I can't figure out a solution to retrieve images from a Parse Table and display it in a Imageview in my Listview.
Here's what i have so far :

```
if (mSchedule.getCount() == 0) {
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("sent_report");
                query.selectKeys(Arrays.asList("Logo"));
                query.selectKeys(Arrays.asList("Couleur"));
                query.selectKeys(Arrays.asList("Date"));
                query.selectKeys(Arrays.asList("Rog_pic"));

                query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                    int i = 0;
                    Bitmap bmp;
                    public void done(List<ParseObject> names, ParseException e) {

                        if (e == null) {
                            for (ParseObject post : names) {
                                postTexts.add(post.getString("Logo"));
                                postTexts.add(post.getString("Couleur"));
                                postTexts.add(post.getString("Date"));

                                ParseFile image = (ParseFile) post.get("Rog_pic");
                                image.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                                    public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                                        if (e == null) {
                                            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

                                        } else {
                                            Log.d("test", "There was a problem downloading the data.");
                                        }
                                    }
                                });

                                map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                                map.put("nom", postTexts.get(i));
                                i++;
                                map.put("titre", postTexts.get(i));
                                i++;
                                map.put("description", postTexts.get(i));
                                i++;
                                map.put("img", bmp);

                                listItem.add(map);
                                mSchedule.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }

                        } else {
                            Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                        }

                    }


                });

            }
```

mSchedule is the SimpleAdapter. I tried a lot of things to make it work. I checked, and the ParseFile is not null, so why aren't the images displayed in the Imageview ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please post the code for your adapter. Thats where the bug is. Are you sure you're performing a setImageBitmap(img) on your image view within the getView on your adapter? We need to see more adapter code to figure this out.